# Z-index not working in an absolutely positioned div

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with `z-index` property on an `absolute`ly positioned div.

Here's my code:

```
<nav>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Nav1</a>
      <div class="sub_nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SubNav1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubNav2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
 </nav>


<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
       sjdhfjdshfjsdhf sdjfhsdjfhsdf jsdhfjsdhfj
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
       jsahdjashdjahsd ajshdjahsdjas jashdjashdjhasjhdja
   </div>
</div>
```

The `nav li` is positioned `relative` and `sub_nav` is positioned `absolute`.
And the list is positioned in left side and tabs in the right side of the screen.
When I hover the `nav li` the `sub_nav` goes behind the `tabs` div.

Here is my Css:

```
.sub_nav{ 
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   top: 0;
   background: #eee;
   width: 200px;
   z-index: 99999
}
```

There is no `z-index` in `tabs` div.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please create fiddle for this.?

Comment: you are missing semi-colon after `z-index: 9999` typo?

Comment: There's an error in the HTML: `<li>` is not supposed to go directly in `<nav>`. Does the problem still happen when you correct that? Also, is there any code (CSS or Javascript) involved in the hovering?

Comment: @Mr_Green a missing semicolon after a style property is not an error. Semicolons are property _separators_, not property _terminators_. So leaving out the one just before the `}` is perfectly fine and there is not a browser in the world that will handle it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly there was a `position:relative` in the `tabs` div.
I removed that and the problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

give z-index: 99; to the `<ul>`

Comment: That won't do anything unless you also give a `position` to the `<ul>`.

Comment: do you mean `z-index: 99;`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not Z-index problem 
you put wrong value '`left:100%`' in '.`sub_nav`' replace this in "`right:0px;"` or as your structure want

this is Fiddle link [visit this](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/29uGQ/)